# GARCH specification - why are $\sigma_t^2$ and $\epsilon_t^2$ not the same?

Tags: variance, estimation, garch

Often times people specify the GARCH model as follows:

$$ \sigma _{t}^{2}=\omega +\alpha _{1}\epsilon _{t-1}^{2}+\cdots +\alpha _{q}\epsilon _{t-q}^{2}+\beta _{1}\sigma _{t-1}^{2}+\cdots +\beta _{p}\sigma _{t-p}^{2}=\omega +\sum _{i=1}^{q}\alpha _{i}\epsilon _{t-i}^{2}+\sum _{i=1}^{p}\beta _{i}\sigma _{t-i}^{2}.$$

I must admit that I am a little confused as to what the difference is between $\sigma_t^2$ and $\epsilon_t^2$. As far as I (though I did) know the squared error terms equal the variance, because of the fact that its mean equal zero.

In other words; what I am wondering is what is the actual "numbers" that is put into $\sigma_t^2$'s place in the equation when estimating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a GARCH model for a time series $x_t$ we have 
\begin{aligned}
x_t&\sim i.i.D(\mu_t,\sigma_t^2), \\
\mu_t&=... \text{ (conditional mean of } x_t \text{ given past information)} \\
\sigma_t^2&=\omega +\sum _{i=1}^{q}\alpha _{i}\epsilon _{t-i}^{2}+\sum _{i=1}^{p}\beta _{i}\sigma _{t-i}^{2} \text{ (conditional variance of } x_t \text{ given past information)} 
\end{aligned}
where $D$ is some distribution parameterized by the conditional mean $\mu_t$ and conditional variance $\sigma_t^2$, and $\epsilon_t:=x_t-\mu_t$ is an additive error term, a random variable itself. Meanwhile, $\sigma_t^2$ is the conditional variance of $x_t$ and simultaneously of $\epsilon_t$, hence, a parameter (an unknown constant). You are right that $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_t^2)=\sigma_t^2$, but that does **not** make for $\epsilon_t^2=\sigma_t^2$.

When we are estimating the model, we treat $\sigma_t^2$ as an unknown parameter and estimate it along with the other parameters such as $\omega$, $\alpha$s and $\beta$s. We are not putting in any numbers in for $\sigma_t^2$ in estimation because conditional variances are unobservable and are never a variable in our dataset (just like the other model parameters).

Comment: +1 However, You seem to be using both $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ to represent the same thing.

Comment: @Glen_b, that is a typo, thank you for spotting it. I will correct that.

Comment: +1 of course. Interesting, thanks. Regarding the estimation, how is it possible to simultaneously estimate the beta's and the sigma's.

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa, that could well be a separate question. I am not that good in estimation specifics, but I think that $\sigma$s come out as by-products. Each of them can be expressed as in the last equation of my answer, so it suffices to specificy an initial $\sigma_0^2$ and the rest follow from the coefficients $\omega$, $\alpha$s and $\beta$s. Hence, estimation actually targets the latter coefficients. Some form of Kalman filter or EM algorithm can be used, but there are probably other alternatives, too.

Comment: I guess that it in that sense is similar to the MA-term variable in an ARMA model. Thanks again.

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa, I wanted to mention that initially, but actually, there is a difference; $\sigma_t^2$s are parameters, while the errors in an MA or ARMA model are latent variables. But yes, there is some similarity there. On the other hand, perhaps $\sigma_t^2$s are more similar to $\mu_t$ than to the errors (and $\mu_t$ can be a by-product of MA or ARMA estimation).